# what to do with ExecutablePath/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test?

Tags: 12.04, boot

Everytime I boot up my 12.04 it warns me about this error, and clicking details says:

```
ExecutablePath/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test
```

Is there anything I can do except keep clicking "don't bother reporting" ?

Please tell me in layman's terms: like, don't tell me to use synaptic, tell me where it's hidden in 12.04?

Comment: Try to reinstall `fglxr`. This is a confirmed bug affecting many people: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nux/+bug/958212

Comment: I really mean layman's terms. I did ctrl-alt-T, and tried shakarans sudo apt-get purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx-* but I got the reply that the driver couldn't be found. Should I follow the rest of his recipe?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this error too, everytime I start up Ubuntu 12.04
I also cannot install fglrx etc etc etc... like you tried.
I could not find an official solution.

Here is my solution:

Open a terminal, then type

sudo su (THEN PRESS THE ENTER KEY)
Password:  Now type in your password  (THEN PRESS THE ENTER KEY)

Now you are the user called root.

Type in:
cd /usr/lib/nux  (THEN PRESS THE ENTER KEY)

Type in:
mv unity_support_test  unity_support_test_hold  (THEN PRESS THE ENTER KEY)

Type in:
reboot (THEN PRESS THE ENTER KEY)

Your system will reboot and the error message won't appear anymore.
At least it's not appearing for me... all gone.

It's kind of a slimey solution, but it worked.

George